# Minimum total container size Python

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm practising some Amazon interview coding exercises and I'm stuck with this exercise.

In a nutshell, given a list `l` and an integer `d`, I have to split the list into d parts such that the sum of the max of each part is the smallest, for example, with `l = [10,2,20,5,15,10,1], d = 3` should return 31 as the best option is `[10,2,20,5,15],[10],[1] -> 20+10+1 = 31`.

Link to the problem: [Problem](https://aonecode.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Amazon-Online-Assessment2-Minimum-Total-Container-Size-min.png)

I thought about splitting the list in 2 and calling recursively with the first part and `d-1`, and taking the max of the second part (this second part will start having one element and we will add an element to this part in each iteration).

I did this and I'm getting the "maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object" error. I know the solution to this problem can be found easily but I want to understand why is this approach not working.

```
def getmin(l, d):
    # base case, if the list has d elements each element will be a sublist
    if len(l)==d: 
        return sum(l)
    else:
        minn = float("inf")
        for i in range(1, len(l)-d+1):
            val = getmin(l[0:-i], d-1) + max(l[-i:])
            if minn > val:
                minn = val
    return minn
```

Comment: Try printing `l` and `d` at the top of your function. I'm pretty sure they're not doing what you expect. You may be overloading `l` both as the possible result and as the input list. You'll need a separate structure for the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list `l` is not a 2d list as your written example, so your algorithm seems to be having trouble keeping the result list that stores the cuts you made to get to a particular point and the input list straight. It's much easier to keep a separate list and accumulate the result onto it, treating `l` as read-only. Not to mention, copying it per recursive call is painful from a performance standpoint.

Before going further, Python recommends [never using `l` as a variable name](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid). Prefer `L`, `nums` or `lst` instead--it's really hard to differentiate `1`, `i` and `l`. I'll use `L` for the rest of the post.

A brute force solution similar to yours would be to run a counter from 0 to `len(L)` and use recursion to try every possibility at every node. At each `i`, we can either append the current number `L[i]` to the last bucket or start a new bucket with `L[i]` as the first element. A small optimization is to only keep the max per bucket instead of all the elements.

Now that you have a brute-force solution, you can slap on a [`cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) to [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) repeated work.

```
from functools import cache
import random

def min_sum_of_max_elems_from_d_cuts(L, d):
    assert len(L) >= d

    @cache
    def find_best_cut(i, cuts):
        if len(cuts) == d and i == len(L):
            return sum(cuts)
        elif len(cuts) > d or i >= len(L):
            return float("inf")

        best = float("inf")

        if cuts: # try extending the current cut by L[i]
            new_cuts = cuts[:-1] + (max(cuts[-1], L[i]),)
            best = min(best, find_best_cut(i + 1, new_cuts))

        #                try making a new cut at L[i]
        return min(best, find_best_cut(i + 1, cuts + (L[i],)))

    return find_best_cut(i=0, cuts=tuple())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tests = [
        dict(L=[10,2,20,5,15,10,1], d=3, result=31),
        dict(L=[10,2,20,5,15,10,1], d=5, result=43),
        dict(L=[5,4,2,4,3,4,5,4], d=4, result=16),
        dict(L=[22,12,1,14,17], d=2, result=39),
    ]

    for test in tests:
        assert min_sum_of_max_elems_from_d_cuts(test["L"], test["d"]) == test["result"]
    
    L = random.Random(42).choices(range(200), k=25)
    assert min_sum_of_max_elems_from_d_cuts(L, d=15) == 1056
```

I'll leave optimizations, bottom-up DP and coming up with a recurrence to the reader. It looks like the same problem as [LeetCode 1335](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-difficulty-of-a-job-schedule/), so the target constraints are `1 <= len(L) <= 300`, `0 <= L[i] <= 1000` and `1 <= d <= 10` so it'll need way more firepower than this to avoid TLE.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and the explanation did help a lot. I appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

For the simple case, where d=1, the solution is just the max of the list

```
def getmin(l, d):
    if d == 1:
        return max(l)
```

When d is greater than 1, the solution is to return the smaller of the head or the tail of the list added to the result of a recursive call

```
def getmin(l, d):
    if d == 1:
        return max(l)
    if l[0] < l[-1]:
        return l[0] + getmin(l[1:], d-1)
    else:
        return getmin(l[:-1], d-1) + l[-1]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but it is not working with the case l = [5,4,2,4,3,4,5,4], d=4
as it is returning 18 when the best solution i 16: [5,4],[2],[4,3],[4,5,4] -> 16

Comment: If you have a link to the problem, that'd make it easier for people to validate their solutions. BTW, how large can `l` and `d` be for this problem?

Comment: done, I added a link to the original problem, I think it is meant to be done with dynamic programming and memoization but I'm not sure if it can be done the way I planned.

Comment: Thanks. Your strategy is fine--it's OK to start with brute force and get correctness first, then slap on a memo or do bottom-up DP once you have something working.